# How to resolve error require() is not defined when calling a function from JavaScript to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a website and found out that Javascript does not have any way to contact a database.  I did some research and found out about node.js.  I created a node.js file and a small portion of my code is:

```
var mysql;
var con;

function initialise() {
  mysql = require('mysql');
  con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "name of the server the database is on",
    user: "name of user that has can add and delete stuff to the database",
    password: "password for the user",
    database: "name of the database"
  });
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}

function getCoach(sql, con) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        reject = (err);
        throw err;
      }
      resolve(rows);
    });
  });
}

async function info() {
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  const results2 = await getCoach("SELECT username, password FROM coach", con);
  return results2;
  con.end();
}
```

I need the require('mysql') inorder to connect with the database.  I tested it out and I can get a connection with the database on this file, but when I called a function in the node.js file through Javascript I got an error saying that require() is not defined.  I did some research and found many things like Browserify to try and fix this issue, but nothing is working.  How do I remove the error so that I can connect to the database that I created through JavaScript.  What am I missing and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you saying you were trying to run the same js file from the browser and it didn't work?

Comment: @Jackyef is right. You have to run this mysql connection on a server and make an api (see 'express' for nodejs). If you want more control on the client side and you're not fixed on mysql I can recommend Firebase by Google, might be an easier setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try including your require statement outside the function like this:

```
const mysql = require("mysql")
```